# Elasticsearch: query produced is invalid

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm getting a little frustrated with elasticsearch, after having read the documents, but can't seem to get beyond a 'The query produced is invalid" response. What I am trying to do is use elasticsearch to find imperfect duplicates in geospatial information and a rather large dataset. I want to match on name (boosted) and address, filter results a small geographic box and then reduce the relevance score of matches that are located further from my reference point. Can someone please help? I think I understnad the individual elements of a query, my main problem is putting these together in a way that products something valid.

```
$query = new \Elastica\Query\Builder('{
        "function_score": {
            "functions": [
                {
                    "gauss": {
                        "location": {
                            "origin": "'.$latitude.', '.$longitude.'",
                            "scale": "2km"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "query": {
                "filtered": {
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "name": {
                                            "query": "'.$name.'",
                                            "boost": 4
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "address": {
                                            "query": "'.$address.'",
                                            "boost": 1
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "filter": {
                        "geo_distance": {
                            "distance": "2km",
                            "location": {
                                "lat": "'.$latitude.'",
                                "lon": "'.$longitude.'"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
    }')
```

Comment: "DECAY_FUNCTION" is not a function. "gauss", "linear" and "exp" are.

Comment: The query is still invalid if I substitute DECAY_FUNCTION for 'guass' for example (I edited the text above to represent that). Any suggestions?

Comment: Spell "gauss" properly, maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

You should surround the whole query by a "query" clause:

```
$query = new \Elastica\Query\Builder('{
"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "functions": [
            {
                "gauss": {
                    "location": {
                        "origin": "'.$latitude.', '.$longitude.'",
                        "scale": "2km"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "query": {
            "filtered": {
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "name": {
                                        "query": "'.$name.'",
                                        "boost": 4
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "address": {
                                        "query": "'.$address.'",
                                        "boost": 1
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "filter": {
                    "geo_distance": {
                        "distance": "2km",
                        "location": {
                            "lat": "'.$latitude.'",
                            "lon": "'.$longitude.'"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}')
```

To have more feedback when making queries, a good habit is to print the Elasticsearch's response to the query.

Try the query in your [SENSE](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense-beta/lhjgkmllcaadmopgmanpapmpjgmfcfig?hl=en):

```
POST test/_search
{
        "function_score": {
            "functions": [
                {
                    "gauss": {
                        "location": {
                            "origin": "11, 12",
                            "scale": "2km"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "query": {
                "filtered": {
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "name": {
                                            "query": "name",
                                            "boost": 4
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "address": {
                                            "query": "address",
                                            "boost": 1
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "filter": {
                        "geo_distance": {
                            "distance": "2km",
                            "location": {
                                "lat": "'.$latitude.'",
                                "lon": "'.$longitude.'"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

You'll get the response:

> SearchParseException[[test][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [function_score]]]; }]

Telling that Elasticsearch doesn't recognize "function_score". By reading in detail the [function_score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) page on the elasticsearch wiki and looking at the example, you'll then find what's missing: the surrounding "query" clause.

PS: Elastica also provides an [alternative syntax](http://elastica.io/getting-started/search-documents.html) for creating the query body with the ElasticaQueryBuilder, which spare you from writing the json.